# Duplicate Custom Header Functionality into the post edit screen

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, media, uploads, media-library

Within wordpress 3.0 you have the ability to create a custom header image with a very slick built in cropping tool.

I found out that the code being utilized for this is located within wp-admin/custom-header.php.

What I am looking to do is including this same functionality within my own custom post type so that I can create many header images and rotate through them while also adding additional fields to each post.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the code from the custom-header.php file.

```
<?php
/**
 * The custom header image script.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 */

/**
 * The custom header image class.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 */
class Custom_Image_Header {

    /**
     * Callback for administration header.
     *
     * @var callback
     * @since 2.1.0
     * @access private
     */
    var $admin_header_callback;

    /**
     * Callback for header div.
     *
     * @var callback
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @access private
     */
    var $admin_image_div_callback;

    /**
     * Holds default headers.
     *
     * @var array
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @access private
     */
    var $default_headers = array();

    /**
     * Holds the page menu hook.
     *
     * @var string
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @access private
     */
    var $page = '';

    /**
     * PHP4 Constructor - Register administration header callback.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     * @param callback $admin_header_callback
     * @param callback $admin_image_div_callback Optional custom image div output callback.
     * @return Custom_Image_Header
     */
    function Custom_Image_Header($admin_header_callback, $admin_image_div_callback = '') {
        $this->admin_header_callback = $admin_header_callback;
        $this->admin_image_div_callback = $admin_image_div_callback;
    }

    /**
     * Set up the hooks for the Custom Header admin page.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    function init() {
        if ( ! current_user_can('edit_theme_options') )
            return;

        $this->page = $page = add_theme_page(__('Header'), __('Header'), 'edit_theme_options', 'custom-header', array(&$this, 'admin_page'));

        add_action("admin_print_scripts-$page", array(&$this, 'js_includes'));
        add_action("admin_print_styles-$page", array(&$this, 'css_includes'));
        add_action("admin_head-$page", array(&$this, 'help') );
        add_action("admin_head-$page", array(&$this, 'take_action'), 50);
        add_action("admin_head-$page", array(&$this, 'js'), 50);
        add_action("admin_head-$page", $this->admin_header_callback, 51);
    }

    /**
     * Adds contextual help.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     */
    function help() {
        add_contextual_help( $this->page, '<p>' . __( 'You can set a custom image header for your site. Simply upload the image and crop it, and the new header will go live immediately.' ) . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __( 'If you want to discard your custom header and go back to the default included in your theme, click on the buttons to remove the custom image and restore the original header image.' ) . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __( 'Some themes come with additional header images bundled. If you see multiple images displayed, select the one you&#8217;d like and click the Save Changes button.' ) . '</p>' .
        '<p><strong>' . __( 'For more information:' ) . '</strong></p>' .
        '<p>' . __( '<a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Header_SubPanel" target="_blank">Documentation on Custom Header</a>' ) . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __( '<a href="http://wordpress.org/support/" target="_blank">Support Forums</a>' ) . '</p>' );
    }

    /**
     * Get the current step.
     *
     * @since 2.6.0
     *
     * @return int Current step
     */
    function step() {
        if ( ! isset( $_GET['step'] ) )
            return 1;

        $step = (int) $_GET['step'];
        if ( $step < 1 || 3 < $step )
            $step = 1;

        return $step;
    }

    /**
     * Set up the enqueue for the JavaScript files.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    function js_includes() {
        $step = $this->step();

        if ( ( 1 == $step || 3 == $step ) && $this->header_text() )
            wp_enqueue_script('farbtastic');
        elseif ( 2 == $step )
            wp_enqueue_script('imgareaselect');
    }

    /**
     * Set up the enqueue for the CSS files
     *
     * @since 2.7
     */
    function css_includes() {
        $step = $this->step();

        if ( ( 1 == $step || 3 == $step ) && $this->header_text() )
            wp_enqueue_style('farbtastic');
        elseif ( 2 == $step )
            wp_enqueue_style('imgareaselect');
    }

    /**
     * Check if header text is allowed
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     */
    function header_text() {
        if ( defined( 'NO_HEADER_TEXT' ) && NO_HEADER_TEXT )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Execute custom header modification.
     *
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    function take_action() {
        if ( ! current_user_can('edit_theme_options') )
            return;

        if ( empty( $_POST ) )
            return;

        $this->updated = true;

        if ( isset( $_POST['resetheader'] ) ) {
            check_admin_referer( 'custom-header-options', '_wpnonce-custom-header-options' );
            remove_theme_mod( 'header_image' );
            return;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['resettext'] ) ) {
            check_admin_referer( 'custom-header-options', '_wpnonce-custom-header-options' );
            remove_theme_mod('header_textcolor');
            return;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['removeheader'] ) ) {
            check_admin_referer( 'custom-header-options', '_wpnonce-custom-header-options' );
            set_theme_mod( 'header_image', '' );
            return;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['text-color'] ) ) {
            check_admin_referer( 'custom-header-options', '_wpnonce-custom-header-options' );
            $_POST['text-color'] = str_replace( '#', '', $_POST['text-color'] );
            if ( 'blank' == $_POST['text-color'] ) {
                set_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', 'blank' );
            } else {
                $color = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-fA-F]/', '', $_POST['text-color']);
                if ( strlen($color) == 6 || strlen($color) == 3 )
                    set_theme_mod('header_textcolor', $color);
            }
        }

        if ( isset($_POST['default-header']) ) {
            check_admin_referer( 'custom-header-options', '_wpnonce-custom-header-options' );
            $this->process_default_headers();
            if ( isset($this->default_headers[$_POST['default-header']]) )
                set_theme_mod('header_image', esc_url($this->default_headers[$_POST['default-header']]['url']));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process the default headers
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     */
    function process_default_headers() {
        global $_wp_default_headers;

        if ( !empty($this->headers) )
            return;

        if ( !isset($_wp_default_headers) )
            return;

        $this->default_headers = $_wp_default_headers;
        foreach ( array_keys($this->default_headers) as $header ) {
            $this->default_headers[$header]['url'] =  sprintf( $this->default_headers[$header]['url'], get_template_directory_uri(), get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
            $this->default_headers[$header]['thumbnail_url'] =  sprintf( $this->default_headers[$header]['thumbnail_url'], get_template_directory_uri(), get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display UI for selecting one of several default headers.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     */
    function show_default_header_selector() {
        echo '<div id="available-headers">';
        foreach ( $this->default_headers as $header_key => $header ) {
            $header_thumbnail = $header['thumbnail_url'];
            $header_url = $header['url'];
            $header_desc = $header['description'];
            echo '<div class="default-header">';
            echo '<label><input name="default-header" type="radio" value="' . esc_attr($header_key) . '" ' . checked($header_url, get_theme_mod( 'header_image' ), false) . ' />';
            echo '<img src="' . $header_thumbnail . '" alt="' . esc_attr($header_desc) .'" title="' . esc_attr($header_desc) .'" /></label>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '<div class="clear"></div></div>';
    }

    /**
     * Execute Javascript depending on step.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    function js() {
        $step = $this->step();
        if ( ( 1 == $step || 3 == $step ) && $this->header_text() )
            $this->js_1();
        elseif ( 2 == $step )
            $this->js_2();
    }

    /**
     * Display Javascript based on Step 1 and 3.
     *
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    function js_1() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var text_objects = ['#name', '#desc', '#text-color-row'];
    var farbtastic;
    var default_color = '#<?php echo HEADER_TEXTCOLOR; ?>';
    var old_color = null;

    function pickColor(color) {
        jQuery('#name').css('color', color);
        jQuery('#desc').css('color', color);
        jQuery('#text-color').val(color);
        farbtastic.setColor(color);
    }

    function toggle_text(s) {
        if (jQuery(s).attr('id') == 'showtext' && jQuery('#text-color').val() != 'blank')
            return;

        if (jQuery(s).attr('id') == 'hidetext' && jQuery('#text-color').val() == 'blank')
            return;

        if (jQuery('#text-color').val() == 'blank') {
            //Show text
            if (old_color == '#blank')
                old_color = default_color;

            jQuery( text_objects.toString() ).show();
            jQuery('#text-color').val(old_color);
            jQuery('#name').css('color', old_color);
            jQuery('#desc').css('color', old_color);
            pickColor(old_color);
        } else {
            //Hide text
            jQuery( text_objects.toString() ).hide();
            old_color = jQuery('#text-color').val();
            jQuery('#text-color').val('blank');
        }
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#pickcolor').click(function() {
            jQuery('#color-picker').show();
        });

        jQuery('input[name="hidetext"]').click(function() {
            toggle_text(this);
        });

        jQuery('#defaultcolor').click(function() {
            pickColor(default_color);
            jQuery('#text-color').val(default_color)
        });

        jQuery('#text-color').keyup(function() {
            var _hex = jQuery('#text-color').val();
            var hex = _hex;
            if ( hex[0] != '#' )
                hex = '#' + hex;
            hex = hex.replace(/[^#a-fA-F0-9]+/, '');
            if ( hex != _hex )
                jQuery('#text-color').val(hex);
            if ( hex.length == 4 || hex.length == 7 )
                pickColor( hex );
        });

        jQuery(document).mousedown(function(){
            jQuery('#color-picker').each( function() {
                var display = jQuery(this).css('display');
                if (display == 'block')
                    jQuery(this).fadeOut(2);
            });
        });

        farbtastic = jQuery.farbtastic('#color-picker', function(color) { pickColor(color); });
        <?php if ( $color = get_theme_mod('header_textcolor', HEADER_TEXTCOLOR) ) { ?>
        pickColor('#<?php echo $color; ?>');
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( 'blank' == get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', HEADER_TEXTCOLOR ) || '' == get_theme_mod('header_textcolor', HEADER_TEXTCOLOR) || ! $this->header_text() ) { ?>
        toggle_text();
        <?php } ?>
        });
</script>
<?php
    }

    /**
     * Display Javascript based on Step 2.
     *
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    function js_2() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    function onEndCrop( coords ) {
        jQuery( '#x1' ).val(coords.x);
        jQuery( '#y1' ).val(coords.y);
        jQuery( '#width' ).val(coords.w);
        jQuery( '#height' ).val(coords.h);
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var xinit = <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>;
        var yinit = <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>;
        var ratio = xinit / yinit;
        var ximg = jQuery('img#upload').width();
        var yimg = jQuery('img#upload').height();

        if ( yimg < yinit || ximg < xinit ) {
            if ( ximg / yimg > ratio ) {
                yinit = yimg;
                xinit = yinit * ratio;
            } else {
                xinit = ximg;
                yinit = xinit / ratio;
            }
        }

        jQuery('img#upload').imgAreaSelect({
            handles: true,
            keys: true,
            aspectRatio: xinit + ':' + yinit,
            show: true,
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: xinit,
            y2: yinit,
            maxHeight: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>,
            maxWidth: <?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>,
            onInit: function () {
                jQuery('#width').val(xinit);
                jQuery('#height').val(yinit);
            },
            onSelectChange: function(img, c) {
                jQuery('#x1').val(c.x1);
                jQuery('#y1').val(c.y1);
                jQuery('#width').val(c.width);
                jQuery('#height').val(c.height);
            }
        });
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php
    }

    /**
     * Display first step of custom header image page.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    function step_1() {
        $this->process_default_headers();
?>

<div class="wrap">
<?php screen_icon(); ?>
<h2><?php _e('Custom Header'); ?></h2>

<?php if ( ! empty( $this->updated ) ) { ?>
<div id="message" class="updated">
<p><?php printf( __( 'Header updated. <a href="%s">Visit your site</a> to see how it looks.' ), home_url( '/' ) ); ?></p>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<h3><?php _e( 'Header Image' ) ?></h3>
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>


<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Preview' ); ?></th>
<td >
    <?php if ( $this->admin_image_div_callback ) {
      call_user_func( $this->admin_image_div_callback );
    } else {
    ?>
    <div id="headimg" style="max-width:<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH; ?>px;height:<?php echo HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT; ?>px;background-image:url(<?php esc_url ( header_image() ) ?>);">
        <?php
        if ( 'blank' == get_theme_mod('header_textcolor', HEADER_TEXTCOLOR) || '' == get_theme_mod('header_textcolor', HEADER_TEXTCOLOR) || ! $this->header_text() )
            $style = ' style="display:none;"';
        else
            $style = ' style="color:#' . get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', HEADER_TEXTCOLOR ) . ';"';
        ?>
        <h1><a id="name"<?php echo $style; ?> onclick="return false;" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <div id="desc"<?php echo $style; ?>><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Upload Image' ); ?></th>
<td>
    <p><?php _e( 'You can upload a custom header image to be shown at the top of your site instead of the default one. On the next screen you will be able to crop the image.' ); ?><br />
    <?php printf( __( 'Images of exactly <strong>%1$d &times; %2$d pixels</strong> will be used as-is.' ), HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT ); ?></p>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" method="post" action="<?php echo esc_attr( add_query_arg( 'step', 2 ) ) ?>">
    <p>
        <label for="upload"><?php _e( 'Choose an image from your computer:' ); ?></label><br />
        <input type="file" id="upload" name="import" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'custom-header-upload', '_wpnonce-custom-header-upload' ) ?>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Upload' ); ?>" />
    </p>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_attr( add_query_arg( 'step', 1 ) ) ?>">
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $this->default_headers ) ) : ?>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Default Images' ); ?></th>
<td>
    <p><?php _e( 'If you don&lsquo;t want to upload your own image, you can use one of these cool headers.' ) ?></p>
    <?php
        $this->show_default_header_selector();
    ?>
</td>
</tr>
    <?php endif;

    if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Remove Image' ); ?></th>
<td>
    <p><?php _e( 'This will remove the header image. You will not be able to restore any customizations.' ) ?></p>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="removeheader" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Remove Header Image' ); ?>" />
</td>
</tr>
    <?php endif;

    if ( defined( 'HEADER_IMAGE' ) ) : ?>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Reset Image' ); ?></th>
<td>
    <p><?php _e( 'This will restore the original header image. You will not be able to restore any customizations.' ) ?></p>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="resetheader" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Restore Original Header Image' ); ?>" />
</td>
</tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

    <?php if ( $this->header_text() ) : ?>
<h3><?php _e( 'Header Text' ) ?></h3>
<table class="form-table">
<tbody>
<tr valign="top" class="hide-if-no-js">
<th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Display Text' ); ?></th>
<td>
    <p>
    <?php $hidetext = get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', HEADER_TEXTCOLOR ); ?>
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="hidetext" id="hidetext"<?php checked( ( 'blank' == $hidetext || empty( $hidetext ) )  ? true : false ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'No' ); ?></label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="0" name="hidetext" id="showtext"<?php checked( ( 'blank' == $hidetext || empty( $hidetext ) ) ? false : true ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'Yes' ); ?></label>
    </p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top" id="text-color-row">
<th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Text Color' ); ?></th>
<td>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="text-color" id="text-color" value="#<?php echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', HEADER_TEXTCOLOR ) ); ?>" />
        <span class="description hide-if-js"><?php _e( 'If you want to hide header text, add <strong>#blank</strong> as text color.' );?></span>
        <input type="button" class="button hide-if-no-js" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Select a Color' ); ?>" id="pickcolor" />
    </p>
    <div id="color-picker" style="z-index: 100; background:#eee; border:1px solid #ccc; position:absolute; display:none;"></div>
</td>
</tr>

    <?php if ( defined('HEADER_TEXTCOLOR') && get_theme_mod('header_textcolor') ) { ?>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><?php _e('Reset Text Color'); ?></th>
<td>
    <p><?php _e( 'This will restore the original header text. You will not be able to restore any customizations.' ) ?></p>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="resettext" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Restore Original Header Text' ); ?>" />
</td>
</tr>
    <?php } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
    <?php endif;

wp_nonce_field( 'custom-header-options', '_wpnonce-custom-header-options' ); ?>
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="save-header-options" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save Changes' ); ?>" /></p>
</form>
</div>

<?php }

    /**
     * Display second step of custom header image page.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    function step_2() {
        check_admin_referer('custom-header-upload', '_wpnonce-custom-header-upload');
        $overrides = array('test_form' => false);
        $file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['import'], $overrides);

        if ( isset($file['error']) )
            wp_die( $file['error'],  __( 'Image Upload Error' ) );

        $url = $file['url'];
        $type = $file['type'];
        $file = $file['file'];
        $filename = basename($file);

        // Construct the object array
        $object = array(
        'post_title' => $filename,
        'post_content' => $url,
        'post_mime_type' => $type,
        'guid' => $url);

        // Save the data
        $id = wp_insert_attachment($object, $file);

        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $file );

        if ( $width == HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH && $height == HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT ) {
            // Add the meta-data
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $file ) );

            set_theme_mod('header_image', esc_url($url));
            do_action('wp_create_file_in_uploads', $file, $id); // For replication
            return $this->finished();
        } elseif ( $width > HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH ) {
            $oitar = $width / HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH;
            $image = wp_crop_image($file, 0, 0, $width, $height, HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, $height / $oitar, false, str_replace(basename($file), 'midsize-'.basename($file), $file));
            if ( is_wp_error( $image ) )
                wp_die( __( 'Image could not be processed.  Please go back and try again.' ), __( 'Image Processing Error' ) );

            $image = apply_filters('wp_create_file_in_uploads', $image, $id); // For replication

            $url = str_replace(basename($url), basename($image), $url);
            $width = $width / $oitar;
            $height = $height / $oitar;
        } else {
            $oitar = 1;
        }
        ?>

<div class="wrap">
<?php screen_icon(); ?>
<h2><?php _e( 'Crop Header Image' ); ?></h2>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_attr(add_query_arg('step', 3)); ?>">
    <p class="hide-if-no-js"><?php _e('Choose the part of the image you want to use as your header.'); ?></p>
    <p class="hide-if-js"><strong><?php _e( 'You need Javascript to choose a part of the image.'); ?></strong></p>

    <div id="crop_image" style="position: relative">
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>" id="upload" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" />
    </div>

    <p class="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="x1" id="x1" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="y1" id="y1" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="width" id="width" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $width ); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="height" id="height" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $height ); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="attachment_id" id="attachment_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="oitar" id="oitar" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $oitar ); ?>" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'custom-header-crop-image' ) ?>
    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Crop and Publish' ); ?>" />
    </p>
</form>
</div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Display third step of custom header image page.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    function step_3() {
        check_admin_referer('custom-header-crop-image');
        if ( $_POST['oitar'] > 1 ) {
            $_POST['x1'] = $_POST['x1'] * $_POST['oitar'];
            $_POST['y1'] = $_POST['y1'] * $_POST['oitar'];
            $_POST['width'] = $_POST['width'] * $_POST['oitar'];
            $_POST['height'] = $_POST['height'] * $_POST['oitar'];
        }

        $original = get_attached_file( $_POST['attachment_id'] );

        $cropped = wp_crop_image($_POST['attachment_id'], $_POST['x1'], $_POST['y1'], $_POST['width'], $_POST['height'], HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH, HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
        if ( is_wp_error( $cropped ) )
            wp_die( __( 'Image could not be processed.  Please go back and try again.' ), __( 'Image Processing Error' ) );

        $cropped = apply_filters('wp_create_file_in_uploads', $cropped, $_POST['attachment_id']); // For replication

        $parent = get_post($_POST['attachment_id']);
        $parent_url = $parent->guid;
        $url = str_replace(basename($parent_url), basename($cropped), $parent_url);

        // Construct the object array
        $object = array(
            'ID' => $_POST['attachment_id'],
            'post_title' => basename($cropped),
            'post_content' => $url,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'guid' => $url
        );

        // Update the attachment
        wp_insert_attachment($object, $cropped);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $_POST['attachment_id'], wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $_POST['attachment_id'], $cropped ) );

        set_theme_mod('header_image', $url);

        // cleanup
        $medium = str_replace(basename($original), 'midsize-'.basename($original), $original);
        @unlink( apply_filters( 'wp_delete_file', $medium ) );
        @unlink( apply_filters( 'wp_delete_file', $original ) );

        return $this->finished();
    }

    /**
     * Display last step of custom header image page.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    function finished() {
        $this->updated = true;
        $this->step_1();
    }

    /**
     * Display the page based on the current step.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    function admin_page() {
        if ( ! current_user_can('edit_theme_options') )
            wp_die(__('You do not have permission to customize headers.'));
        $step = $this->step();
        if ( 1 == $step )
            $this->step_1();
        elseif ( 2 == $step )
            $this->step_2();
        elseif ( 3 == $step )
            $this->step_3();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Extend from the existing class and only change the parts you need to change to add your needed functionality: `class MyHeader extends Custom_Image_Header{ .... }` but I suppose this is only scratching the edge what you're really looking for.

Comment: I essentially just want to add the ability to a custom post type page I created for the user to select/upload a file and crop that image based an a size defined within the functions.php file. I don't know if you have played with the header image feature but it's very cool and hooks into auto creating a post also within the media library which is exactly what I need. I would greatly appreciate if you could provide a solution to this painful problem.

Comment: Have you considered to open a ticket in wordpress trac about your feature request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're looking for custom header support for custom post types.

By default WordPress does not offer such a thing for custom post types. The features that are offered for CPTs are listed here: [Arguments for register post type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments).

So this is not easily possible.